# matplotlib export with functions

Tags: matplotlib

Is there any way to export the plot with the functions of matplotlib?
I need the zoom function but i dont want to create the plot new every time because it takes about two minutes.

If someone knows a way to do so please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean to write the plot/image to a file?

Comment: No. I want to save the plot but the functions like zoom should still work. I dont want a static .jpg! I thought maybe there is some way to export it that way.

Comment: You can save the plot and then import it in another session. Check out the tutorial in this link: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html I haven't done it before but it looks cool. The image is represented by a numpy array. I don't know if this is what you want but it might be helpful.